# Firebase not working with Nodejs and Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, firebase, ubuntu, firebase-admin

**Environment**

```
Nodejs => 16
Ubuntu => 18

"firebase-admin": "^11.10.1",
"firebase-functions": "^3.20.1",
```

We have recently migrated firebase to v11 but it is breaking. I confirm that all the modules are there in **node_modules** folder.

Here is the code:

**firebase-util.ts**

```
import { getMessaging } from 'firebase-admin/messaging';
import { cert, getApps, initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';

import constants from "./constants";
import config from "../config/app-config";

export class FirebaseUtil {
firebaseApp: any;
firebaseMessaging: any;

constructor() {
    this.setupFireBase();
}

public setupFireBase() {
    let serviceAccount = require(constants.PATH.PROFILES + "firebase/serviceAccountKey.json");

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
        credential: cert(serviceAccount),
        apiKey: config.FIREBASE.API_KEY,
        authDomain: config.FIREBASE.AUTH_DOMAIN,
        projectId: config.FIREBASE.PROJECT_ID,
        storageBucket: config.FIREBASE.STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: config.FIREBASE.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: config.FIREBASE.APP_ID
    };

    const alreadyCreatedAps = getApps();

    // Initialize Firebase
    this.firebaseApp = alreadyCreatedAps.length === 0 ?
        initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "cocfirebase") : alreadyCreatedAps[0];

    this.firebaseMessaging = getMessaging(this.firebaseApp);
}

async pushMessage(token: string, title: string, body: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = {
            notification: {
                body: body,
                title: title
            }
        };

        // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
        // registration token.
        this.firebaseMessaging.sendToDevice(token, data).then((response: any) => {
            // Response is a message ID string.
            resolve({
                success: true,
                message: response
            });
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            resolve({
                error: error,
                success: false
            });
        });
    });
}
}
```

Here is the error we are getting:

```
0|coc  | Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin/messaging'
0|coc  | Require stack:
0|coc  | - /root/workspace/coc-server/dist/utils/firebase-util.js
0|coc  | - /root/workspace/coc-server/dist/server.js
0|coc  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
0|coc  |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:61:29)
0|coc  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
0|coc  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/root/workspace/coc-server/src/utils/firebase-util.ts:1:1)
0|coc  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
0|coc  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
0|coc  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
0|coc  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
0|coc  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
0|coc  |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
0|coc  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
0|coc  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/root/workspace/coc-server/src/services/doctor-serv.ts:10:1)
0|coc  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
0|coc  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
0|coc  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
```

Here is the directory structure:

```
root@node36514-coc-php-test:~/server/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib# ls -l
total 108
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 app
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 app-check
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 auth
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 credential
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 database
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  742 Sep  3 08:01 default-namespace.d.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1210 Sep  3 08:01 default-namespace.js
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 esm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 eventarc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 extensions
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4280 Sep  3 08:01 firebase-namespace-api.d.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4239 Sep  3 08:01 firebase-namespace-api.js
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 firestore
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 functions
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  738 Sep  3 08:01 index.d.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1405 Sep  3 08:01 index.js
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 installations
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 instance-id
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 machine-learning
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 messaging
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 project-management
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 remote-config
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 security-rules
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 storage
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:01 utils
```